# Bootstrapping multiple nodes with Chef

Tags: chef-infra, bootstrapping

1 have 500 servers in my production environment and I have to deploy 5 applications on these servers.
So app1 will go on 1-100 servers, app2 will go on 101-200 and so on.
I have following questions-

1. How can I bootstrap multiple nodes at the same time?
2. How will I bind the first 100 servers to first run_list and next 100 to second run_list etc.

Comment: Those servers are running already the operating system or will you provision them from scratch via PXE etc?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be some `for` loops in bash plus `knife bootstrap`. Might take a while to run, but since you only have to do this once, it's probably fine.

```
for name in $(cat servers.txt | head -n 100); do knife bootstrap -N $name -r 'role[app1]' $name; done
for name in $(cat servers.txt | tail -n +101 | head -n 100); do knife bootstrap -N $name -r 'role[app2]' $name; done
for name in $(cat servers.txt | tail -n +201 | head -n 100); do knife bootstrap -N $name -r 'role[app3]' $name; done
for name in $(cat servers.txt | tail -n +301 | head -n 100); do knife bootstrap -N $name -r 'role[app4]' $name; done
for name in $(cat servers.txt | tail -n +401 | head -n 100); do knife bootstrap -N $name -r 'role[app5]' $name; done
```

Or something like that.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am a bit confused about chef metal. is it also for the same purpose?

Comment: It is now known as chef-provisioning, and bootstrapping Chef is a feature but it expects to be creating the servers via a cloud service. I also do not recommend you use chef-provisioning anymore as the project is kind of in stasis, Terraform can also do stuff like this, but again it would probably be overkill if this is a one-time thing.